# QML FileDialog - set quantity limit on files to select

Tags: qt, qml

How to limit amount of files to load using QML FileDialog? I could raise a message if count of selected files is bigger than 5 for example. But it seems like bad solution.

```
 FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title: qsTr("Please select an image")
        folder: shortcuts.pictures

        selectMultiple: true
        selectFolder: false

        nameFilters: [ "Images (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)" ]

        onAccepted: {
            for(var i = 0; i < fileDialog.fileUrls.length; i++){ //bigger than 5 what to do?
                urlModel.append({
                    url: fileUrls[i]
                })
            }
        }
        onRejected: {}
    }
```

Comment: I guess this function doesn't exist

Comment: @folibis what could you suggest?

Comment: The easiest way - to inform a user ... to get the 5 first files ... some workaround, you know. Another way is to request the change from the Qt team or to change the QtQuick source by yourself since that's open source.